# Monitoring incoming requests on a web hosting server

Tags: linux, http, port, webserver, netcat

I have a web hosting account with GoDaddy (its a Linux based hosting). Can I install applications like netcat to monitor all incoming requests to my website on a certain port? If not, is there any other way I can do that?

I have a page that accepts POST data, and I need to send the POST data from hardware level. I'm sending the data but apparently its not in the correct format. I want to be able to see the exact request being received on the server end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not possible. You have to ask the godaddy server to do the same for you and if allowed they will surely do it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it wouldn't be possible since I wouldn't have root access on a shared server. I'll try emailing GoDaddy.